# How to install cscope for Mac OS X 10.6

Tags: xcode, osx-snow-leopard, cscope

How can I install cscope for Mac OS X 10.6? I have installed XCode but I don't see cscope in /opt/local/bin.

Comment: Worked for me code.google.com/p/rudix/downloads/detail?name=cscope-15.7a-3.pkg&can=2&q=label%3AOSX-SnowLeopard

Answer (score 6):

Download from http://sourceforge.net/ (latest: cscope-15.8a) and in `src/constants.h`, change this line:

```
#if (BSD || V9 ) && !__NetBSD__ && !__FreeBSD__
```

To:

```
#if (BSD || V9 ) && !__NetBSD__ && !__FreeBSD__ && !__APPLE__
```

Then run:

```
configure
make
make install
```

You can find cscope in /usr/local/bin/

Comment: With the latest cscope-15.8b you don't need to edit that line any more.

Comment: Yes, I did not edit the source as of 2023.

Answer (score 0):

I installed cscope on Mac OS X 10.8 using MacPorts:
http://www.macports.org/install.php

There is a cscope port that you can install using the instructions.
After that, I added /opt/local/bin to the path.

Answer (score 0):

FWIW, I just got the source, no mods to source, did the regular

- `./configure`
- `make`
- `sudo make install`